# Spring Batch MultiThreaded Step Execution

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have my jdbcPagingReader and JpaItemWriter configured.
I am invoking a job with a step which has multi thread task executor as below.

```
public Step step() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("myJob")
                .chunk(500)
                .reader(jdbcPagingItemReader)
                .writer(jpaItemWriter)
                .taskExecutor(MySimpleAsyncTaskExecutor)
                .throttleLimit(100)
                .build();
    }
```

But i see very less number of records getting committed into database even after long time .
I have set the page size which is equal to chunk/commit interval size.

What could be the possible mistake i am doing here..?

Logs for Reference

```
2019-01-14 19:08:07.257 DEBUG 3100 --- [TaskExecutor 25] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=33
2019-01-14 19:08:07.257 DEBUG 3100 --- [TaskExecutor 79] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=19
2019-01-14 19:08:07.257 DEBUG 3100 --- [TaskExecutor 75] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=36
2019-01-14 19:08:07.257 DEBUG 3100 --- [TaskExecutor 49] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=37
2019-01-14 19:08:07.257 DEBUG 3100 --- [askExecutor 100] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=13
2019-01-14 19:08:07.257 DEBUG 3100 --- [TaskExecutor 69] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=20
2019-01-14 19:08:07.257 DEBUG 3100 --- [TaskExecutor 72] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=19
2019-01-14 19:08:07.257 DEBUG 3100 --- [TaskExecutor 36] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=36
2019-01-14 19:08:07.257 DEBUG 3100 --- [-TaskExecutor 7] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=37
2019-01-14 19:08:07.258 DEBUG 3100 --- [TaskExecutor 18] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=72
2019-01-14 19:08:07.258 DEBUG 3100 --- [TaskExecutor 84] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=22
2019-01-14 19:08:07.258 DEBUG 3100 --- [TaskExecutor 86] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=20
2019-01-14 19:08:07.258 DEBUG 3100 --- [TaskExecutor 74] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=21
2019-01-14 19:08:07.258 DEBUG 3100 --- [TaskExecutor 65] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=39
2019-01-14 19:08:07.258 DEBUG 3100 --- [TaskExecutor 17] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=26
2019-01-14 19:08:07.258 DEBUG 3100 --- [TaskExecutor 20] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=22
2019-01-14 19:08:07.258 DEBUG 3100 --- [TaskExecutor 51] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=16
2019-01-14 19:08:07.258 DEBUG 3100 --- [TaskExecutor 33] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=14
2019-01-14 19:08:07.258 DEBUG 3100 --- [TaskExecutor 28] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=16
2019-01-14 19:08:07.258 DEBUG 3100 --- [TaskExecutor 31] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=26
2019-01-14 19:08:07.258 DEBUG 3100 --- [TaskExecutor 76] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=19
2019-01-14 19:08:07.258 DEBUG 3100 --- [TaskExecutor 95] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=11
2019-01-14 19:08:07.258 DEBUG 3100 --- [TaskExecutor 64] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=9
2019-01-14 19:08:07.258 DEBUG 3100 --- [TaskExecutor 12] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=10
2019-01-14 19:08:07.258 DEBUG 3100 --- [-TaskExecutor 8] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=9
2019-01-14 19:08:07.258 DEBUG 3100 --- [-TaskExecutor 1] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=10
2019-01-14 19:08:07.258 DEBUG 3100 --- [TaskExecutor 39] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=10
2019-01-14 19:08:07.258 DEBUG 3100 --- [TaskExecutor 99] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=14
2019-01-14 19:08:07.258 DEBUG 3100 --- [TaskExecutor 41] o.s.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate  : Repeat operation about to start at count=8
```

Comment: Have you set `saveState=false` as mentioned in the [Javadoc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcPagingItemReader.java#L65-L70)?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine yes I have set save state to false in my JdbcPagingItemReader

Comment: In fact when i don't set taskexecutor, the frequency at which the  records get inserted to database using writer is more

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine  i have added additional logs.Can you please throw some light on it